# Exact diagonalization by Bogoliubov transformation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, fermions, hamiltonian

I am developing a model of multiple gaps in a square lattice. I simplified the associated Hamiltonian to make it quadratic. In this approximation it is given by,

$$
H =
\begin{pmatrix}
\xi_\mathbf{k} & -\sigma U_1 & -U_2 & -U_2\\
-\sigma U_1 & \xi_{\mathbf{k}+(\pi,\pi)} & 0 & 0\\
- U_2 & 0 & \xi_{\mathbf{k}+(\pi/2,0)} & 0\\
- U_2 & 0 & 0 & \xi_{\mathbf{k}+(0,\pi/2)}.
\end{pmatrix}
$$

And my Nambu operator is given by,

$$
ψ_\mathbf{k} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
c_{\mathbf{k},\sigma} \\
c_{\mathbf{k}+(\pi,\pi),\sigma} \\
c_{\mathbf{k}+(\pi/2,0),\sigma} \\
c_{\mathbf{k}+(0,\pi/2),\sigma}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I tried to diagonalized by making three Bogoliubov transformations, the first to diagonalize the upper right submatrix of $H$, and then the two others (a sort of nested transformations). But I get a lengthy result, what I would like to know if there is a smart transformation which allows me to write

$$ H = A_1^\dagger A_2^\dagger A_3^\dagger D A_3 A_2 A_1 $$

or simply

$$ H = U^\dagger D U .$$

Or the only way is to use just brute force? My question may be rephrase as, is there any elegant representation or expression of the diagonalization as for example the one obtained in BCS Superconductivity?

Comment: Just type the matrix into Mathematica, and use Eigensystem to let computer do the job. Are you trying to get analytical result? It seems that your matrix  has no elegant eigenvalue.

Comment: Hi, I did the same but as I mentioned above the result is very lengthy and hard to read without doing the numerics. I would like to obtain a result which simple analytically speaking. The shape of the matrix reminds me the matrix of the electromagnetic field in General Relativity so I was wondering if there was some trick for its diagonalization. Anyway it is a long shot and as you mention maybe the only way is just to use the computer.

Comment: It is the typical problem of using mathematica to find the eigenstates. I usually look for some patterns and then hand substitute some terms there. The results will quickly shorten by few order of magnitude. You may need an hour to do that, but it worth if you really need analytic results. You may get some tips by asking question at Mathematica.SE here

Comment: Thanks a lot, I definitely will do that if I find an interesting result I will add it as a comment.