# Canonical transformation for the "nearly diagonal" Hamiltonians

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, group-theory, hamiltonian

**The Hamiltonians in question** are the Hamiltonians that have all the non-diagonal equal to zero except for the first row and the first column (assuming for simplicity that $U_i\in\mathbb{R}$ are real):
$$
H_2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon_0 & U_1 \\
U_1 & \epsilon_1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
H_3 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon_0 & U_1 & U_2\\
U_1 & \epsilon_1 & 0 \\
U_2 & 0 & \epsilon_2
\end{bmatrix},
$$
$$
H_4 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon_0 & U_1 & U_2 & U_3\\
U_1 & \epsilon_1 & 0 & 0 \\
U_2 & 0 & \epsilon_2 & 0 \\
U_3 & 0 & 0 & \epsilon_3
\end{bmatrix},
$$
and so on.

**Relevance to physics**
Such Hamiltonians are quite ubiquitous, and many people could come with the examples typical for their field. I will mention just a few:

- Coupled sublattice sites (order $n$ of $H_n$ is typically 3 or 4, see also [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89257/247642))
- A level coupled to a band (order $n$ is very large)
- Anderson impurity (with some complications added)

**Solvability**
Many particular cases of this Hamiltonian are solvable: e.g., when all the couplings are the same ($U_1=U_2=...=U_{n_1}$) and the number of levels is infinite (broad-band limit for a resonant level) or if $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2=...=\epsilon_{n-1}\neq \epsilon_0$, when the characteristic equation can be reduced to a quadratic equation.

Moreover, in cases $n=3$, $n=4$ the characteristic equation is exactly solvable in principle, although the results may not look pretty.

**Question**
What is the general form of a canonical transformation for diagonalizing such Hamiltonians?

For $n=3$ and $n=4$ this would amount to a simply convenient parametrization, whereas for arbitrary $n$ it is a transformation that takes into account the greater simplicity of this Hamiltonians in comparison to a general $n\times n$ Hamiltonian.

To suggest a specific line of reasoning: the canonical transformation matrix for a real Hamiltonian is an orthogonal matrix with $n(n-1)/2$ independent parameters ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/63340/765359), e.g.). However, the zeros in the Hamiltonian impose additional $(n-1)(n-2)/2$ constraints, thus leaving only $n-1$ independent parameters.

**Update**
I am looking for a closed analytical expression parametrized in terms of $n-1$ parameters, which could be unknown. For example, this could be $n-1$ eigenvalues - since we are not sure that they can be found analytically for $n>4$ (a definitive statement to this end would be also handy). I might be already providing an answer here...

Comment: Just for clarification: are you asking whether there is a *closed analytic* expression for the eigenvectors of this class of symmetric matrices?

Comment: @TomášBrauner I hoped for some nice, intuitive symmetric expression, like the rotation matrix for 2-by-2 case... but yes, technically you have pointed out a solution, although not a very pretty one.

Comment: Note that a solution to the problem you describe can be used recursively diagonalise any symmetric matrix. Based on our understanding of the complexity of the latter problem this constrains the complexity of finding a solution to your specific problem.

Comment: Using Household transformation (an special orthogonal transformation) for the n-1 column vector $(U_1, U_2, ..., U_n$). This will transform into a 2x2 symmetric matrix.

Comment: @ytlu can you elaborate? I cannot see how to combine an $n \times n$ matrix, and a vector of length $n-1$ to obtain a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Comment: @ytlu could you show how to do this? This could qualify as an answer right away.

Comment: @Vadim unfortunately ytlu's method cannot work. The characteristic polynomials of your matrices $H_n$ do not factorise into quadratic equations, and so cannot be transformed to $2 \times 2$ problems by a matrix whose elements are linear combinations the matrix elements of $H_n$.

Comment: My mistake. The Household transformation may changes the allready diagonal $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ submatrix.

Comment: This should have a nice interpretation in terms of perturbation theory, since the matrix is only every coupling the 1st state to one of the others, and back.  And perturbation theory can be interpreted as decoupling the two diagonal blocks to any given order.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch if you could write an infinite perturbation series solution in terms of $U_i$ or something like that, it would be interesting. This is certainly something that I haven't tried yet.

Comment: @Vadim Well, one way to think about perturbation theory is to do a rotation which sets the block coupling the ground and excited space to zero up to the order of the perturbation expansion.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch One could consider diagonal part of the Hamiltonian as unperturbed or one could consider degenerate case $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2=...=\epsilon_{n-1}$ as unperturbed - depending on the problem, obviously.

Comment: I'd say eps_0 is the ground state, and the rest the excited state. The U_i are the perturbations which couple ground to excited states.

Comment: One thing you can see is that for the ground state, 2nd order should be exact, since higher orders correspond to terms where you stay in the excited space, and there are no transitions elements for that (except for trivial ones, which should be easy to take care of).

Answer (score 4):

The working matrix $(n+1)\times (n+1)$:
$$
\mathbf{H} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
  \epsilon_0 & U_1 & U_2 & U_3 & ... &U_{n-1}&U_n\\
  U_1 & \epsilon_1 &0&0&...&0&0\\
  U_2& 0 & \epsilon_2 &0&...&0&0\\
  U_3& 0 & 0 & \epsilon_3 &...&0&0\\
  ...&...&...&...&...&....&...\\
   U_{n-1} &0&0&0&...&\epsilon_{n-1}&0\\ 
  U_n &0&0&0&...&0&\epsilon_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Assum that all $U_i \ne  = 0$, and are real numbers. The eigen equation for this matrix:

$$ \tag{1}
det\left( \mathbf{H} - \lambda \mathbf{I} \right) = 0
$$
Since $\mathbf{H}$ is a symmetric real matrix, it guarantees that there exists $n+1$ real eigen values and the corresponding $n+1$ orthogonal eigen vectors.

A closed form of the eigen equation can be obtained by Gauss-Jordan elimination. First, add to the first row, the $n$th row mutiplied by $-\frac{U_n}{\epsilon_n -\lambda}$. This will leave $H_{0n}=0$, 
 and adds  a term to $H_{00}$, $H_{00} = (\epsilon_0 - \lambda)  -\frac{U_n^2}{\epsilon_n -\lambda}$.
 
Repeat this process for $i = n-1, n-2, ... 1$. After $n$ eliminations, the upper triangular elements of $\mathbf{H} - \lambda \mathbf{I}$ becomes all zeros, and the element $H_{00}$ collects $n$ more terms from the elimination process:

$$ \tag{2}
H_{00} = (\epsilon_0 - \lambda) - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{U^2_i}{\epsilon_i - \lambda}.
$$

and the determinant is the product of all diagonal elements:

$$
det\left(\mathbf{H} - \lambda \mathbf{I} \right) = \left\{ (\epsilon_0 - \lambda) - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{U^2_i}{\epsilon_i - \lambda} \right\} \prod_{i=1}^n (\epsilon_i - \lambda).
$$
$$ \tag{3}
 = \prod_{i=0}^n (\epsilon_i - \lambda)  - \sum_{i=1}^n U^2_i \prod_{j=1, j\ne i}^n (\epsilon_j - \lambda).
$$

**Case 1. Degenerate diaginal elements**

In case that there are some energies are equal, saying 3-fold degeneracy: $\epsilon_a = \epsilon_b = \epsilon_c$
 for $a$, $b$, $c$ are arbitrary three integers in $\{1,2,3, ..., n\}$.

Under this case, a term $(\epsilon_a - \lambda )^2$ can be factored out of the Eq. (3).
The energy $\epsilon_a$ is therefore an eigen value of degeneracy $3-1=2$. The corresponding
eigen vectors can be calculated from the $4\times 4$ submatrix:

$$ \tag{4}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \epsilon_0-\epsilon_a & U_a & U_b & U_c\\
  U_a & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  U_b & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  U_c & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_0\\
  x_a\\
  x_b\\
  x_c
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  0\\
  0\\
  0\\
  0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The equation for eigen vectors:
$$  x_0   = 0;$$
$$  x_a U_a + x_b U_b + x_c U_c = 0. $$

Two orthonomal eigen vectors can be constructed from these two conditions. *It would be very interesting to observe how these two domension block-diaginalized and decoupled from the rest $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ dimensions, and how the coupling elements is changed for the remaining state of the 3 degenerate levels.*

We conclude that for $p$-fold degeneracy energy $\epsilon_a$, ther existed $(p-1)$ degenerate eigen vectors with eigen value $\lambda = \epsilon_a$. This $(p-1)$ basis vectors span an $(p-1)$ subspace. The motion of the subspace is decoupled from the rest of the system. One example realized this matrix is a coupled oscillator system, which all the oscillators are coupled only to the $0$th oscillator (see Figure). The dynamical matrix for the normal mode will resemble this matrix form. Then, we can select a subgroup of oscillation modes, that they are coupled only within the subgroup.

[image: coupled OSC]

Another worthy mentioned situation is that all $\epsilon_i = \epsilon_1$ for all $i=1, 2, 3,..,n$. Then we immediately has $n-1$-fold eigen values $\lambda = \epsilon_1$. Their eigen vectors span the $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ subspace.

$$ \vec{v}_\lambda = [x_0, x_1, x_2, ..., x_{n-1}, x_n] $$

Conditions for eigen vector:

$$   x_0 = 0;$$
$$  \sum_{i=1}^n x_i U_i = 0. $$

Since we have $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ symmetric matrix, there are two more eigen values. From the determinant, after factoring out $(\epsilon_1-\lambda)^{n-1}$, we find that the last two eigen values are the root of the equation:
$$
   (\epsilon_0-\lambda) (\epsilon_1-\lambda) - \sum_{i=1}^n U_n^2 = 0.
$$
Which is two-level matrix with coupling strength $U =\sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^n U_n^2} $. The eigen values are readily given:
$$
   \lambda_\pm = \frac{\epsilon_0+\epsilon_1}{2} \pm \sqrt{ \frac{(\epsilon_0-\epsilon_1)^2}{2} + U^2}
$$
The total $n+1$ eigen values consist of $(n-1)$-fold of $\epsilon_1$ in the middle and two $ \lambda_\pm$ in higher and lower values.

**Non-degenrate case**

we may now assume that all $\epsilon_i$ are different. All eigen values will then solely determined by zeros of the element $H_{00}$ in Eq.(2)':
{2}
$$
H_{00} = (\epsilon_0 - \lambda) - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{U^2_i}{\epsilon_i - \lambda} = 0.
$$
$$
   = (\epsilon_0 - \lambda) - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{U^2_i}{(\epsilon_i-\epsilon_0 ) -( \lambda -\epsilon_0 ) } = 0.
$$

Setting $\epsilon_0 = 0$ without lossing generality:
$$
   = -\lambda - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{U^2_i}{\epsilon_i  - \lambda } = 0.
$$

For better understanding of this equation, lets assum $\epsilon_i = i $. We can now examine the value of $H_{00}(\lambda)$ by scanning $\lambda$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

The value of $H_{00}(\lambda)$ is positive when $\lambda \ll 0 $, but the term of summation is negative. Just before $\lambda \to 0^-$, the smaller negative summation catches up with $-\lambda$. It is the smallest eigen value (the $\lambda_-$ in the total degenerate case.)

Then the $H_{00}$  approach $-\infty$ at $\epsilon_1^-$ due to divergence in
$-\frac{U_1^2}{\epsilon_1 - \lambda}$. After $\lambda = \epsilon_1^+$, the function emerges with large positive value. And approach $-\infty$ again at $\epsilon_2^-$, behaves like the $\cot$ function. Therefore, it locates first eigen value at $\lambda_0 <0$, and $n-1$ eigen values at $\epsilon_i < \lambda_i < \epsilon_{i+1}$, a final eigen value locates
at $\lambda_n > \epsilon_n $, because when
$\lambda \to \infty$, $H_{00} \to -\infty$, as shown in Fig.(2).

[image: H00]

We can see this figure topologically, as $\epsilon_1$,..$\epsilon_n$ are drawn closer, and finally into one energy $\epsilon_1$. All the levels in between, are forced collapse into a single degenerate level, but the first and the last, stay away from this squeezing process.

**pertubation for small $U_i$'s**

In case that $U_i \ll |\epsilon_a - \epsilon_b|$ for any two diagonal element, $\epsilon_a$, and
$\epsilon_b$. The eigen value and eigen vector can be obtained by a approximation method similar
to the second order perturbation in quantum mechanics:

$$
  \lambda_0 = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{U_i^2}{\epsilon_i}.
$$
Where is replace the $\lambda$ in the summation by $\epsilon_0 = 0$.

For $i \ge 1$
$$
  \lambda_i = \epsilon_i + \frac{U_i^2}{\epsilon_i - \epsilon_0} = 
  \epsilon_i + \frac{U_i^2}{\epsilon_i}.
$$
Where we replace the $\lambda$ in the summation by $\epsilon_i$, and made expansion for small $U_i$s.

**Eigen vectors and tranformation**

Each eigen value renders an eigen vector $\vec{v}_\lambda = \left[ x_0, x_1, x_2, ...,x_n \right] $:
$$
\vec{v}_\lambda = A_1
\begin{bmatrix}
   1, \frac{U_1}{\lambda - \epsilon_1},  \frac{U_2}{\lambda - \epsilon_2}, ...,  \frac{U_n}{\lambda - \epsilon_n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Leave $A_1$ as the normalization constant. There are $n$ ortho-normal vectors, providing the bases for the orthogonal transformation $\mathbf{R}$ to the diagonalisation of the Hamiltonian.

$$
\mathbf{R} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
A_0 & A_1 & A_2 & A_3& ... & A_n\\
\frac{A_0 U_1}{\lambda_0 - \epsilon_1} &\frac{A_1 U_1}{\lambda_1 - \epsilon_1} & \frac{A_2 U_2}{\lambda_2 - \epsilon_2} &\frac{A_3 U_1}{\lambda_3 - \epsilon_1} & ... & \frac{A_{n} U_1}{\lambda_{n} - \epsilon_1}\\
\frac{A_0 U_2}{\lambda_0 - \epsilon_1} &\frac{A_1 U_2}{\lambda_1 - \epsilon_2} & \frac{A_2 U_2}{\lambda_2 - \epsilon_1} &\frac{A_3 U_2}{\lambda_3 - \epsilon_2} & ... & \frac{A_{n} U_2}{\lambda_{n} - \epsilon_2}\\
....&... & ... & ... & ... \\
\frac{A_0 U_{n}}{\lambda_0 - \epsilon_1} & \frac{A_1 U_{n}}{\lambda_1 - \epsilon_{n}} & \frac{A_2 U_{n}}{\lambda_2 - \epsilon_{n}} & \frac{A_3 U_{n}}{\lambda_3 - \epsilon_{n}} &... & \frac{A_{n} U_{n}}{\lambda_{n} - \epsilon_{n}}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Since the $\mathbf{H}$ is Hermitian, the $n+1$ eigen vectors are mutually orthogonal:

$$
\mathbf{R} \mathbf{R}^T =\mathbf{R}^T \mathbf{R} = \mathbf{I}
$$
$$
 \mathbf{R}^T \mathbf{H}\mathbf{R} =\mathbf{D}
$$
Where $\mathbf{D}$ is the diagonal matrix with all $\lambda_i$ as the elements.

Lets consider a matrix equation:
$$
  \mathbf{H} \vec{v} = \vec{w}
$$

Transform it to the eigen coordinate:
$$
 \mathbf{R}^T \mathbf{H} \left(\mathbf{R} \mathbf{R}^T \right) \vec{v} = \mathbf{R}^T\vec{w}
$$
$$
 \mathbf{D} \left( \mathbf{R}^T \vec{v} \right) = \left(\mathbf{R}^T\vec{w}\right)
$$
$$
 \mathbf{D} \vec{v}'  = \vec{w}'
$$

In $\vec{v}'$ and $ \vec{w}'$ primed coordinate, the matrix $\mathbf{D}$ is diagonalized, thus each components of  $\vec{v}'$ and $ \vec{w}'$ is decoupled.

The transformation
$$
 \mathbf{R}^T  \vec{w} = \vec{w}' ;
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{R}  \vec{w}' = \vec{w} ;
$$

Comment: Case 1 is just the general case - in terms of canonical transformation one still has $n$ unknown eigenvalues and $n-1$ normalization constants the canonical transformation. It is not clear what the case 2 is differznt ftom case 3. In case 3 - what are $H_1$ and $H_2$? It is not clear to me, if you are really onto something new...

Comment: There are $n$ roots from the Eq. (1), and reders $n$ eigen vectors.

Comment: @Wolpertinger equation 1 is the standard eigenvalue equation $|H-\lamba I|=0$. It is easily written for $n=2,3,4$ and generalized to higher order by induction.

Comment: @Wolpertinger what you are saying is correct for an *arbitrary* n-by-n Hamiltonian, it doesn't bring us closer to understanding the Hamiltonians in question. General polynomial equation of order $n$ is not solvable, but there are many particular cases which are solvable. E.g., the degenerate case $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2=...\epsilon_{n-1}$ is exactly solvable for arbitrary $n$, $\epsilon_0$, and $U_1, U_2,...,U_{n-1}$ - as pointed out in the question.

Comment: @Wolpertinger I don't think that there's any special *physics* in writing a characteristic equation and expressing matrix eigenvectors in terms of eigenvalues - everyone learns to do so in an undergraduate linear algebra and/or quantum mechanics course. This is the elementary stuff.

Comment: @ytlu thnk you for streamlining your answer. Note that *Gaussian elimination* is a method of solving the systems of linear equations, not of calculating determinants.

Comment: @Vadim I change the term into Gauss-Jordan elimination. They are very similar.

Comment: @ytlu but it still has nothing to do with the eigenvalue equation: *Using Gaussian elimination leads to the eigen equation*

Comment: @Vadim lLets make all upper triagular elements zero. Start from eliminating the last element  $H_{0n}=U_n$. Add to the first row the $n$th  row multiply  an appropriate coefficient,  $-U_n / ( \epsilon_n - \lambda)$. This makes $H_{0n} = 0$ and adds the term $U_n^2 / (\epsilon_n - \lambda)$ to the $H_{00}$ element. Continue the process until all $H_{0i}$ vanishes. The product of the diagonal elements is the determinant. Since all $H_{ii} = \epsilon_i - \lambda$ are not zero, all roots comes from the element $H_{00}$.

Comment: @ytlu Yes, this is how one solves a system of linear equations - it could be technically used for calculating the eigenvectors in the second half of your post, although it would be an overkill. However, it has nothing to do with evaluating a determinant - which is where it appears in your answer - your very first equation (before (1)) is already the eigenvalue equation and you get to (1) by the straightforward Laplace expansion. There is no place for a Gaussian elimination there.

Comment: @Vadim No. elimination method is much easier for computing the determinant. It is the classical method for determinant. Now-a-day, we use LU decomposition. It is also a  method of elimination. I couldn't get such a clear form as Eq(1), if employed the Laplace development. BTW, your normalization constant $A_i$ needed inverse.

Comment: @ytlu Getting Eq. (1) by Laplace expansion is trivial. Also, if you insist on LU decomposition - once your matrix has upper or lower triangular elements zero, the determinant is simply the product of the diagonal elements.

Comment: As I indicated previously, your answer didn't really give me new insights. However, I do appreciate your efforts, and I recognize that the question was not precisely formulated. And sinc eno one offered a better answer, I award the full bounty to you rather than throwing it away.

Comment: @Vadim Thank you. I take the reward as a demand for a more presentable post. I will late refine my post to make it more rich in content.

Comment: I am done with the revision. Please let me know if there are errors.

Answer (score 1):

this is not a complete solution just some idea

$$\mathbf A=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \epsilon _{{1}}&U_{{1}}&U_{{2}}
\\ U_{{1}}&\epsilon _{{2}}&0\\ U_{
{2}}&0&\epsilon _{{3}}\end {array} \right] 
$$

**Step I**

Transform  $~\mathbf A~$ to

$$\mathbf B=\mathbf J^T\,\mathbf A\,\mathbf J=
\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&{\frac {U_{{1}}}{\sqrt {\epsilon _{{1}}}
\sqrt {\epsilon _{{2}}}}}&{\frac {U_{{2}}}{\sqrt {\epsilon _{{1}}}
\sqrt {\epsilon _{{3}}}}}\\ {\frac {U_{{1}}}{\sqrt {
\epsilon _{{1}}}\sqrt {\epsilon _{{2}}}}}&1&0\\ {
\frac {U_{{2}}}{\sqrt {\epsilon _{{1}}}\sqrt {\epsilon _{{3}}}}}&0&1
\end {array} \right] 
\mapsto  \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&U_{{1}}&U_{{2}}\\ U_{{
1}}&1&0\\ U_{{2}}&0&1\end {array} \right] 
$$

with:
$$\mathbf J=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} {\frac {1}{\sqrt {\epsilon _{{1}}}}}&0&0
\\ 0&{\frac {1}{\sqrt {\epsilon _{{2}}}}}&0
\\ 0&0&{\frac {1}{\sqrt {\epsilon _{{3}}}}}
\end {array} \right] 
$$

**Step II**

transform $\mathbf B$ to diagonal shape.
Ansatz:
$\mathbf B_d=~\mathbf T^T\,\mathbf B\,\mathbf T-I_3=\mathbf 0$

with :

$$\mathbf T=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&1&1\\ {\it T21}&1&1
\\ {\it T31}&{\it T32}&1\end {array} \right]
$$

you get three equations

$$eq_1=1+U_{{1}}+{\it T32}\,U_{{2}}+{\it T21}\,U_{{1}}+{\it T21}+{\it T31}\,U
_{{2}}+{\it T31}\,{\it T32}
=0$$
$$eq_2=1+{\it T21}\,U_{{1}}+{\it T31}\,U_{{2}}+U_{{1}}+{\it T21}+U_{{2}}+{
\it T31}
=0$$
$$eq_3=2+2\,U_{{1}}+{\it T32}\,U_{{2}}+U_{{2}}+{\it T32}=0$$

for the three unknows $~T21~,T31~,T32$

Results:

$$\mathbf T=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&1&1\\ -{\frac {U_{{1}}
+1-{U_{{2}}}^{2}}{U_{{1}}+1}}&1&1\\ -U_{{2}}&-{
\frac {2+2\,U_{{1}}+U_{{2}}}{U_{{2}}+1}}&1\end {array} \right]
$$

$$B_d(1,1)=-{\frac {2\,{U_{{1}}}^{3}+ \left( 2-{U_{{2}}}^{2} \right) {U_{{1}}}^{2
}+ \left( -2+2\,{U_{{2}}}^{2} \right) U_{{1}}-2-{U_{{2}}}^{4}+3\,{U_{{
2}}}^{2}}{ \left( U_{{1}}+1 \right) ^{2}}}
$$
$$B_d(2,2)=4\,{\frac {{U_{{1}}}^{2}}{ \left( U_{{2}}+1 \right) ^{2}}}+{\frac {
 \left( -2\,{U_{{2}}}^{2}+4\,U_{{2}}+10 \right) U_{{1}}}{ \left( U_{{2
}}+1 \right) ^{2}}}+{\frac {-3\,{U_{{2}}}^{2}+4\,U_{{2}}+6-2\,{U_{{2}}
}^{3}}{ \left( U_{{2}}+1 \right) ^{2}}}
$$
$$B_d(3,3)=3+2\,U_{{1}}+2\,U_{{2}}$$

and $~B_d(i,j)=0~,i\ne j$

for

$$\mathbf B=\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&U_{{1}}&U_{{2}}&U_{{3}}
\\U_{{1}}&1&0&0\\ U_{{2}}&0&1&0
\\ U_{{3}}&0&0&1\end {array} \right]
$$

$$\mathbf T=\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&1&1&1\\ {\frac {U_{{
1}}+1-{U_{{3}}}^{2}-{U_{{2}}}^{2}}{U_{{1}}+1}}&1&1&1
\\ -U_{{2}}&-{\frac {2+2\,U_{{1}}+U_{{2}}-{U_{{3}}}^
{2}}{U_{{2}}+1}}&1&1\\ -U_{{3}}&-U_{{3}}&-{\frac {3+
2\,U_{{1}}+2\,U_{{2}}+U_{{3}}}{U_{{3}}+1}}&1\end {array} \right] 
$$

you can try now to find  a pattern between the transformation matrix $~\mathbf T_{n=3}~$ and  $~\mathbf T_{n=4}~$ if you find  a pattern you can obtain the transformation matrix $~\mathbf T_{n}~$

Comment: I've been thinking about this approach as well. In principle, once you have a matrix with equal diagonal elements, you csn find all the eigenvalues (see my own answer). The problem is that your transformation $J$ is not a unitary/orthogonal: $J^T\neq J^{-1}$...

Comment: I've been thinking about this approach as well. In principle, once you have a matrix with equal diagonal elements, you csn find all the eigenvalues (see my own answer). The problem is that your transformation $J$ is not a unitary/orthogonal: $J^T\neq J^{-1}$...

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** Due to the disagreement (in the comments) about what should be considered an answer to my question I post this here: it refines the existing answer and raises more precise questions about what needs to be understood for a complete treatment of this problem.

**Standard approach to eigenvalue problems** includes

1. Solving the characteristic equation for the eigenvalues, $$|H-\lambda I|=0,$$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.
2. Solving the eigenvectors equations, given known eigenvalues,
   $$
   H\mathbf{x}=\lambda \mathbf{x}.
   $$

*The characteristic equation*
Evaluating determinants is is trivial for this type of the Hamiltonians. In particular we obtain:
$n=2$
$$
|H-\lambda I| = \left|\begin{matrix} \epsilon_0-\lambda & U_1 \\ U_1 & \epsilon_1 - \lambda \end{matrix}\right|
=(\epsilon_0 - \lambda)(\epsilon_1-\lambda) - U_1^2 = 0
$$
$n=3$
$$
|H-\lambda I| = 
(\epsilon_0 - \lambda)(\epsilon_1-\lambda)(\epsilon_2-\lambda) - U_1^2(\epsilon_2-\lambda) - U_2^2(\epsilon_1-\lambda) = 0
$$
$n=3$
$$
|H-\lambda I| = 
(\epsilon_0 - \lambda)(\epsilon_1-\lambda)(\epsilon_2-\lambda)(\epsilon_3-\lambda) - U_1^2(\epsilon_2-\lambda)(\epsilon_3-\lambda) - U_2^2(\epsilon_1-\lambda)(\epsilon_3-\lambda) -U_3^2(\epsilon_1-\lambda)(\epsilon_2-\lambda) = 0
$$
One can then show by induction that for an arbitrary order we get:
$$
|H-\lambda I| = (\epsilon_0 - \lambda)\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (\epsilon_i - \lambda) -  \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}U_i^2 \prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^{n-1} (\epsilon_i - \lambda) = \\
\left(\epsilon_0 - \lambda - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{U_i^2}{\epsilon_i-\lambda}\right)\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (\epsilon_i - \lambda)=0
$$
The last form of the determinant obviously makes sense only if the roots are not equal to any of $\epsilon_i, i>0$. It is also easily seen that, if any two energies are equal $\epsilon_i=\epsilon_j$, one can factor out $\epsilon_i-\lambda$, obtaining one root of the equation.

**Q1: The non-trivial question on the level of the characteristic equation is: can it be solved or can it be shown that it cannot be solved for $n>0$. Note that while the latter statement is known to be true for a general polynomial equation, it is not clear *a priori* that this is also the case for this particular form.**

*Solving for eigenvectors*
Assuming that the eigenvalues $\lambda_i, i=1,..,n$ are known, we can solve for the eigenvectors (Note that this is again a standard procedure for an arbitrary matrix Hamiltonian). For simplicity we assume that none of the roots is equal to any of the energies $\epsilon_j$, although we will show that the solution can be represented in a general form, suitable for a degenerate case.

The solution for this types of the Hamiltonians is trivial (formally one could call it a trivial case of Gaussian elimination). The eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ takes form:
$$
\mathbf{x}_i = A_i\begin{bmatrix} 1\\\frac{U_1}{\lambda_i - \epsilon_1}\\\frac{U_2}{\lambda_i - \epsilon_1}\\...\\\frac{U_{n-1}}{\lambda_i - \epsilon_{n-1}}\end{bmatrix},
$$
where
$$
A_i = \left[1 + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{U_j^2}{(\lambda_i - \epsilon_j)^2}\right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}.
$$
Note that by replacing $1$ in the first element in the eigenvector with $\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}(\lambda_i-\epsilon_j)$ we could remove singularities from thz denominators, obtaining the answers that are also valid for a non-degenerate case.

The canonical transformation diagonalizing the Hamiltonian ($S^\dagger H S = \Lambda$, where $\Lambda_{ij} = \delta_{i,j}\lambda_i$) can be written as
$$
\mathbf{S} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
A_1 & A_2 & ... & A_3\\
\frac{A_1 U_1}{\lambda_1 - \epsilon_1} & \frac{A_2 U_1}{\lambda_2 - \epsilon_1} & ... & \frac{A_{n} U_1}{\lambda_{n} - \epsilon_1}\\
\frac{A_1 U_2}{\lambda_1 - \epsilon_2} & \frac{A_2 U_2}{\lambda_2 - \epsilon_2} & ... & \frac{A_{n} U_2}{\lambda_{n} - \epsilon_2}\\
... & ... & ... & ... \\
\frac{A_1 U_{n-1}}{\lambda_1 - \epsilon_{n-1}} & \frac{A_2 U_{n-1}}{\lambda_2 - \epsilon_{n-1}} & ... & \frac{A_{n} U_{n-1}}{\lambda_{n} - \epsilon_{n-1}}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This canonical transformation is parametrized by $n$ eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, which can be considered as parameters: even if we fail to solve the characteristic equations the canonical transformation will have this form.

**Q2: Contrary to what was suggested in the OP, the transformation diagonalizing an arbitrary n-by-n Hamiltonian is parametrizable in terms of its $n$ eigenvalues. So the question is about the special constrains and the number of independent parameters that we have in case of the simpler Hamiltonians considered in this question. Given the presence of the additional constrains - shouldn't there exist a relation between the eigenvalues, meaning that some cases with $n>4$ are actually exactly solvable?**

*Simpler form of the canonical transformation*
The canonical transformation above can be written as
$$
\mathbf{S} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & \frac{U_1}{U} & ... & 0 \\
... & ... & ... & ... \\
0 & 0 & ... & \frac{U_{n-1}}{U}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
A & A & ... & A\\
\frac{A U}{\lambda_1 - \epsilon_1} & \frac{A U}{\lambda_2 - \epsilon_1} & ... & \frac{A U}{\lambda_{n} - \epsilon_1}\\
\frac{A U}{\lambda_1 - \epsilon_2} & \frac{A U}{\lambda_2 - \epsilon_2} & ... & \frac{A U}{\lambda_{n} - \epsilon_2}\\
... & ... & ... & ... \\
\frac{A U}{\lambda_1 - \epsilon_{n-1}} & \frac{A U}{\lambda_2 - \epsilon_{n-1}} & ... & \frac{A U}{\lambda_{n} - \epsilon_{n-1}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{A_1}{A} & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & \frac{A_2}{A} & ... & 0 \\
... & ... & ... & ... \\
0 & 0 & ... & \frac{A_n}{A}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This decomposition is more obvious, if we take $U=A=1$, but defining these factors as
$$
U=\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}U_i\right)^{\frac{1}{n-1}},\\
A=\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}
$$
preserves the dimensionality and assures that we are dealing with a product of three canonical transformations (three unitary/orthogonal matrices).

**Q3: The ultimate holy grail here would be to have a representation of the canonical transformation that is manifestly unitary and "symmetric" in the way the well-known rotation matrices are for $n=2$ and $n=3$. At present these properties are hidden in the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$.**

**Other possible approaches**

- Canonical transformation with an ad-hoc parametrization of the transformation matrix (e.g., using [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform))
- Formal perturabtion expansion to all orders of magnitude, e.g., using the resolvent operator
- Using an auxhiliary transformation, as suggested by @Eli

Comment: From eigen vectors to the answer of Q3 is a process of elementary physical math. It is orthogonal (unitary for complex matrix), but not symmetric. If your symmetry means dual transformation, then again, it is a buit-in property of an orthogonal matrix. All these features have been granted in the form of the Hamiltonian - a hermitian matrix.

Comment: @Wolpertinger I appreciate your efforts, but think you at_ytlu simply do not understand the problem - probably because you lack experience with relevant physical problems. Please let others contribute.

Comment: @Wolpertinger Should I consider it as a threat or revenge? Moderators would normally point out that you do not close the question that you answer and vice versa. You in fact not only tried to answer it, but also tried to promote another answer.